# Integer decode porting from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, .net, integer, decode

I am trying to port some code from java to C#, I have faced 2 problems so far. Here is the Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    var ia = new byte[args.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        try
        {
            ia[i] = Integer.decode(args[i]).byteValue();
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
        }
    System.out.
    println(Integer.toHexString(Calc(ia, ia.length)));
}
```

Obviously I have to change `main` to `Main`, `length` to `Length` but no idea about:

`Integer.decode(args[i]).byteValue()`

and

`Integer.toHexString(Calc(ia, ia.length))`.

Can someone tell me please what are the avilable options in .NET in these cases?!

Comment: if you're specifically trying to convert from hex values in string format to integer (and backwards), you may want to check [this article on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx)

Comment: what do Calc means in your code?

Comment: Look at the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) of class `Integer` to find out what the `decode` and `toHexString` methods do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible conversion code from `java` to `c#.Net`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var ia = new byte[args.Length];

     for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
     try
     {
        ia[i] = Convert.ToByte(args[i]);
     }
     catch (FormatException e)
     {
     }
   System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:X}",Calc(ia, ia.Length))); /// I assume Calc is function return something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convert.toInt32(string) or Parse.Int32(string)

Comment: Should I use this for both `Integer.decode` and `Integer.toHexString` ?